# Unity 3d, increase speed smoothly (automatic)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple cube, and I wrote this script for moving cube, but i need that the speed of the object increase over time, but doesn't work...

***I need to move the cube in the x axis without point of arrival.***

public float speed = 0.5f;
    public bool active = false;

```
float currentSpeed = 1f;
float maxSpeed = 50f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    speed = 0f;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

        active = true;

    }

    if(active == true)
    {

        Move();
    }
}

void Move() {

    if (currentSpeed < maxSpeed)
    {

        currentSpeed += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(currentSpeed * (Time.deltaTime / 2), 0, 0);
        Debug.Log("Speed: " + currentSpeed);
    }
    else {

        transform.Translate(50f, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is currentspeed increasing as a variable? why would you take currentspeed at say 40, and multiply it by time.deltatime/2 and then when it it hits 50 just apply 50? that wont give a smooth transition as time.deltatime is tinytiny and then suddenly that value becomes 50

Comment: I know my code is wrong, as soon as it exit the if loop, the cube accelerates abnormally @BugFinder

Comment: so what happens if you change the translate to just use currentspeed as it stands?

Comment: to do this, i need to increase over time the value of "currentSpeed" over time..

Comment: right but you are increasing currentspeed in the line before, just use the translate with only the currentspeed, and then you can slowly tinker with the equation for increasing the speed of currentspeeds increase such as deciding its += time.deltatime/2 or whatever if the increase is faster or time.deltatime*5 if its too slow

Comment: @BugFinder So just increase only the current speed with a "low" float number?

Comment: If i use "AddForce"? Could I solve my problems?

Comment: there are a number of ways to solve it, the key is the right logic for any of them ..   do you want linear acceleration, or a more bolder rolling down hill so start slow and gain quicker?

Comment: @BugFinder I want linear acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html).
This will smoothly increase a vector you can use as speed. It may look similar to this :

```cs
Vector3 targetPositon; // Where you want the cube to move to.
Vector3 refVelocity = Vector3.zero; // This is used inside the function, don't touch!
float smoothing = 0.5f; // How much smoothing there should be.

void Update() {
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition,
    ref refVelocity, smoothing);
}
```

`SmoothDamp` will return a Vector3 that gradually gets closer to a target and accelerates / decelerates like a spring.

Edit, another idea :
Another thing you could do is have the some velocity `v` that you add to the position each frame and times it by a number like `1.01f` or any small number greater than one. This is a little crude but works.

Comment: Thanks, but the cube will not have a target position because the cube will have to move on the x axis indefinitely, however increasing the speed

Comment: Not on Unity right now, but you could have the target be `transform.position + Vector3.right`, unsure how the speed would react there. Give it a go though. I'll stick an edit on the answer for a different idea as well.

Comment: I tried, but didn't work as I wish... I need a simple movement to x asix that increase its speed automatically over time

Comment: How about the edit? That's about as simple as you could do this. `transform.position = transform.position * 0.1f;`

Answer (score 0):

Think your code works just very very slowly. After all you increase the speed by delta which is about (1000/60) (at 60fps) perframe but apply that value multiplied with ((1000/60)/2).

Are you sure you do not want to make use of Unity's physics engine? With it you could use the function AddForce to accelerate an object in a realistic way.

Comment: I need that the increase is slow, but with my code, the cube doesn't increase in speed.. With "AddForce" can i increase the cube speed(force) smoothly?